# Why have coding over configuration at all?

Tags: spring, configuration

When we talk about spring (which ever module say jdbc), one of the reasons we use it is because it enables dependency injection and controls lifecycle of beans/classes. In programming, one of the most important fundamental is to code for interfaces rather than implementations, so today if I am using sql server driver v1, I can change it to v2 tomorrow if my code is written in such a way that it cares about Driver interface and not the implementations, then in what case would I ever need coding over configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

The wording of your question seems a bit strange to me. Perhaps you are asking if there are any drawbacks to using Spring-like dependency injection. I can think of a few drawbacks, but whether these drawbacks outweigh the potential benefits of Spring is a matter of opinion.

1. Unfortunately, a Spring XML file is much more verbose than code to achieve similar (but hard-coded) initialisation of objects.
2. A programmer has to look not just at code but also at a Spring XML file to figure out what is going on. This, arguably, is a form of the [Yo-yo problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yo-yo_problem).
3. One significant benefit of Spring is that it can be used to instantiate and configure *any* Java class (assuming the classes provide getters and setters). In particular, Java classes do not need to be polluted with the need to inherit from framework infrastructure classes. *If* you don't mind polluting classes with the need to inherit from framework infrastructure, then it is possible to have much more concise configuration files for instantiating and configuring objects. A case study illustrating this idea can be found in Chapters 9, 10 and 11 of the [Config4* Practical Usage Guide](http://www.config4star.org/download/manuals/config4star-practical-usage-guide.pdf). I am not proposing that the approach used in that case study be used for all applications, but I think it is a good approach to use when there is a complex, standardised API (such as for JMS) that is implemented by multiple products. In the case study, the approach results in a significantly easier-to-use API and eliminates some potential bugs from applications. Spring doesn't offer such benefits.
4. Section 9.4.2 of the [Config4* Practical Usage Guide](http://www.config4star.org/download/manuals/config4star-practical-usage-guide.pdf) outlines a 9-step initialisation process for typical JMS applications. The framework library discussed in the case study ensures that those 9 steps are carried out in the correct order. It has been years since I looked at Spring so I might be wrong, but I don't think Spring has the flexibility to (easily or perhaps at all) enforce such a complex 9-step initialisation mechanism.